# convert: Memory allocation failed

Tags: python, python3, imagemagick

```
    '''PYTHON3
            bash = "width=`identify -ping -format '%w' {}` ".format('design_adjusted.png')
            bash += "height=`identify -ping -format '%h' {}` ".format('design_adjusted.png')
            bash += "wx=$(($width-1)) hy=$(($height-1)) "
            bash += "coords='0,0 657,926  ${},0 1254,1067  ${},${} 1133,2051  0,${} 419,1803' ".format('wx','wx','hy','hy')
            bash += "width=`identify -ping -format '%w' {}` ".format('template_white.png') 
            bash += "height=`identify -ping -format '%h' {}` ".format('template_white.png')
            bash += "dims='${}x${}'  ".format('width','height')
            bash += 'convert \\ -size $dims xc:none \\  \\( {} -alpha set -virtual-pixel transparent '.format('design_adjusted.png')
            bash += '+distort Perspective "$coords" \\) \\-geometry +419+926 -compose Over -composite design_positioned.png'
            os.system(bash)
            if os.path.isfile("/home/rexweb/Desktop/project/design_positioned.png"):
                    return "<h1>SUCCESS</h1>"
            return '<h1>ERROR</h1>'
```

'''

Comment: And what is your question exactly?  How does it relate to Ubuntu?

Comment: i am using imagemagick for converting and posiioning of image over one another. when i run the above code it says memory allocation failed in terminal while running os commands.

Comment: So, you use bash to run a python program that runs a bash command?  Looks complex to me. anyway, the bash command you run (with line `os.system(bash)` starts with `width ='identify...`.  It is no bash command at all.  As I see no reference to imagemagick in your code, I think you forgot something.

Comment: these are command of imagemagick running in os.system(bash) .  i would upload the file on a CDN and send you link if you could help.